# Unique UnPivot SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is how the data looks like currently

```
OrderNo, OrderDate, Order_PROD1, Order_Unit1, Order_IP1_Date, Order_PROD2, 
1        12/20/2017 17383         894YU        12/23/2017      49348       

Order_Unit2, Order_IP2_Date ...... Order_PROD30, Order_Unit30, 
489UI         11/12/2015
```

The way i want to transform is

```
OrderNo, OrderDate, Order_Prod,    Order_Unit,   Order_IP_Date
1         12/20/2017 17383         894YU         12/23/2017
1         12/20/2017 49348         489UI         11/12/2015    
1         12/20/2017 Order_Prod3*  Order_Unit3*  Order_IP3_Date*    
1         12/20/2017 Order_Prod4*  Order_Unit4*  Order_IP4_Date*  


Order_Prod3* = Value of column Order_Prod3
Order_Prod4* = Value of column Order_Prod4
```

Here is the query i have so far

```
 select Orderid, OrderDate, Order_Prod, Order_unit, Order_IP_Date
 from tbl
 unpivot
(
    Order_Prod ??????
    for Order_Prod in (Order_Prod1, Order_Prod2, Order_Prod3)???
) unpiv;
```

Not sure how to un-pivot on multiple columns..

Comment: Had a glaring omission on the accepted answer.   Put a quick fix in the final Group By

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Dynamic version (Notice I added a second record as an illustration)

```
Declare @YourTable table (OrderNo int,OrderDate date,Order_PROD1 varchar(25),Order_Unit1 varchar(25),Order_IP1_Date date,Order_PROD2 varchar(25),Order_Unit2 varchar(25),Order_IP2_Date date,Order_PROD3 varchar(25),Order_Unit3 varchar(25),Order_IP3_Date date)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'2017-12-20','17383','894YU','2017-12-23','9999','AAA-894YU','2017-12-31','a9999','bAAA-894YU','2017-12-28'),
(2,'2017-12-22','17999','89999','2017-12-27','8888','BBB-894YU','2017-12-29','b8888','bBBB-894YU','2017-12-30')

Declare @XML xml = (Select *,RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By OrderNo Order By OrderNo) from @YourTable for XML RAW)

Select OrderNo
      ,OrderDate
      ,OrderRow      = Replace(Substring(Item,PatIndex('%[0-9]%',Item),2),'_','')
      ,Order_Prod    = max(case when Item Like 'Order_Prod%' then Value else null end)
      ,Order_Unit    = max(case when Item Like 'Order_Unit%' then Value else null end)
      ,Order_IP_Date = max(case when Item Like 'Order_IP%'   then Value else null end)
From (
        Select OrderNo   = r.value('@OrderNo','int')
              ,OrderDate = r.value('@OrderDate','date')
              ,RN        = r.value('@RN','int')
              ,Item      = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
              ,Value     = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
         From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(r)
         Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
         Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('OrderNo','OrderDate','RN')
      ) A
 Group By OrderNo,OrderDate,RN,Replace(Substring(Item,PatIndex('%[0-9]%',Item),2),'_','')
```

Returns

```
OrderNo OrderDate       OrderRow    Order_Prod  Order_Unit    Order_IP_Date
1       2017-12-20      1           17383       894YU         2017-12-23
1       2017-12-20      2           9999        AAA-894YU     2017-12-31
1       2017-12-20      3           a9999       bAAA-894YU    2017-12-28
2       2017-12-22      1           17999       89999         2017-12-27
2       2017-12-22      2           8888        BBB-894YU     2017-12-29
2       2017-12-22      3           b8888       bBBB-894YU    2017-12-30
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a Cross Apply may help here.  UnPivot has greater performance, but you will have a little more flexibility.

```
Declare @YourTable table (OrderNo int,OrderDate date,Order_PROD1 varchar(25),Order_Unit1 varchar(25),Order_IP1_Date date,Order_PROD2 varchar(25),Order_Unit2 varchar(25),Order_IP2_Date date,Order_PROD3 varchar(25),Order_Unit3 varchar(25),Order_IP3_Date date)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'2017-12-20','17383','894YU','2017-12-23','9999','AAA-894YU','2017-12-31','a9999','bAAA-894YU','2017-12-28'),
(2,'2017-12-22','17999','89999','2017-12-27','8888','BBB-894YU','2017-12-29','b8888','bBBB-894YU','2017-12-30')

Select A.OrderNo
      ,A.OrderDate
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Values (1,A.Order_Prod1,A.Order_Unit1,A.Order_IP1_Date)
                     ,(2,A.Order_Prod2,A.Order_Unit2,A.Order_IP2_Date)
                     ,(3,A.Order_Prod3,A.Order_Unit3,A.Order_IP3_Date)
                     -- ...
                     --,(30,A.Order_Prod30,A.Order_Unit30,A.Order_IP30_Date)
             ) B (OrderRow,Order_Prod,Order_Unit,Order_IP_Date)
```

Returns

```
OrderNo OrderDate       OrderRow    Order_Prod  Order_Unit    Order_IP_Date
1       2017-12-20      1           17383       894YU         2017-12-23
1       2017-12-20      2           9999        AAA-894YU     2017-12-31
1       2017-12-20      3           a9999       bAAA-894YU    2017-12-28
2       2017-12-22      1           17999       89999         2017-12-27
2       2017-12-22      2           8888        BBB-894YU     2017-12-29
2       2017-12-22      3           b8888       bBBB-894YU    2017-12-30
```